# Scrapy, login with captcha failed

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, captcha

I'm using the following spider for crawling the *tinyz.us* website that requires an authentication.

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import urllib2


class Start(BaseSpider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ["http://tinyz.us"]

    def parse(self, response):

        user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
        headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
        imgRequest = urllib2.Request("http://tinyz.us/securimage/securimage_show.php", headers=headers)
        imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgRequest).read()

        with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgData)

        captcha = raw_input("-----> Enter the captcha in manually :")

        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response=response,
            formdata={"login_user": "myusername",
                      "login_password": "mypass",
                      "captcha_code": captcha},
            formxpath="//*[@id='login-form']",
            callback=self.after_login,
            headers=headers)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print("AFTER LOGIN")
        with open('response.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

The website uses a constant url for generating the captcha and it seems that each time it generates a new one. I'm not familiar with the respective tech but they way that I tend to get around that problem is saving the captcha and passing it manually.

The problem is that it always returns a failed response, I'm not sure if the problem is because of the way that scrapy passes the data to `form` or because of the captcha and I can't find a way to debug the spider properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, the problem here is that the captcha image needs to receive the cookies from the actual response, and you are using `urllib2` to make the captcha request, so Scrapy isn't handling that by default.

Use a scrapy request to check the captcha, something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield Request(url="http://tinyz.us/securimage/securimage_show.php", callback=self.parse_captcha, meta={'previous_response': response})

def parse_captcha(self, response):
    with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)

    captcha = raw_input("-----> Enter the captcha in manually :")

    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response=response.meta['previous_response'],
        formdata={"login_user": "myusername",
                  "login_password": "mypass",
                  "captcha_code": captcha},
        formxpath="//*[@id='login-form']",
        callback=self.after_login)
```

Comment: So how should I involve the `captcha` after entering the characters manually. You're not using it in `parse` function. Also what's that `Request`  inside the `parse`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the unnecessary part from `parse`, please check updated answer

Comment: It raises  `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError`

Comment: it says you don't have a `parse` method in your spider, also import request: `from scrapy import Request`

Comment: Yes, also I changed the meta to `response.meta` and it worked correctly. Thanks!